# Can telescope have dual purpose?

Tags: optics, lenses, telescopes, microscopy

Astronomical telescope has a small eye piece and a large objective lens. Whereas a compound microscope has a large eye piece and small objective lens. Therefore can we use astronomical telescope as compound microscope by viewing it from objective lens?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74128/ (the answer there notes that a telescope is optimised for magnifying far away objects whilst microscopes are optimised for nearby ones).

Comment: So can we use it as least efficient microscope

Comment: Ya, I understood that microscope increases the size of the object to view it clearly, whereas telescope brings the object closer as image to view it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Telescopes are usually not build with magnification in mind. It is rather having the highest possible angular resolution! You want to be able to distinguish two spot-like light sources close to each other, not to see them as large as possible but smeary. Therefore, you want to have your telescope dish as large as possible. I think you just have another purpose than with an enlarging microscope...

Or was your question rather theoretically?

Comment: Yes my question is theoretical.